# Nodejs module.exports and Shorthand if/else

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

What does the line `'undefined' != typeof Customer ? Customer : module.exports` in the following code snippet do? And why do you wrap everything within `(function(){})`? I cant seem to decipher its meaning

This snippet comes from a library file.

```
(function (Customer) {

  Customer.Base = {
    //...
  }

})(
  'undefined' != typeof Customer ? Customer : module.exports

);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is ternary that is used to determine what is passed to the function. The function is an Immediately-invoked function exppression (IIFE) - a function that is created and immediately invoked.

```
//the condition
'undefined' != typeof Customer
//true value
? Customer 
//false value
: module.exports
```

If `Customer` is undefined, this is the same result:

```
(function (Customer) {

  Customer.Base = {
    //...
  }

})(module.exports);
```

So this code block is creating and immediately invoking a function that does something to a `Customer`. If `Customer` is defined, `Customer` is passed to the function as the function argument which is also named `Customer`. If `Customer` is undefined, `module.exports` is passed to the function as the `Customer` argument. This code could be rewritten as:

```
var param;
if ('undefined' != typeof Customer) {
  param = Customer;
} else {
  param = module.exports;
}

function myFunc(Customer) {

  Customer.Base = {
    //...
  }

}

myFunc(param);
```

It may be easier to understand in a more generic example.

Here's an IIFE, a function that is created and immediately invoked: **[Live demo (click).](http://jsbin.com/eWEYalO/1/edit)**

```
(function(param) {
    console.log(param);
})('some param!');
```

and here's that same function, using ternary to determine the param value: **[Live demo (click).](http://jsbin.com/eWEYalO/2/edit)**

```
var x = true;
//var x = false;

var value = x ? 'true value!' : 'false value!';

(function(param) {
    console.log(param);
})(value);
```

Change `x` (the condition) to true or false and see that the assigned value of `value` is changed accordingly.

You may often see the ternary condition wrapped in `()`, but they are not necessary:

```
('undefined' != typeof Customer) ? Customer : module.exports
```

Further, it is more typical to see that statement asked the opposite way:

```
typeof Customer === 'undefined'
```

and it is likely that a simple loose equality check for "truthiness" would suffice here:

```
Customer ? Customer : module.exports
```

and that could again be simplified to:

```
Customer || module.exports
//if "Customer" is truthy, it will be used, otherwise, module.exports is used
```

Also note that with an IIFE, the can be `})()` or `{())`, the latter being the more typical syntax.